# My google cookies with selenium web driver are not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to do login to google, then save the cookies, and when I open another browser the account should already be signed in with the cookies, the login works, but the cookies don't seem to work when I open another browser.

Code that saves my cookies:
cookies = browser.get_cookies()

```
pickle.dump(cookies, open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))
```

Code that loads them:

```
for cookie in cookies: 

    cookie['domain'] = '.google.com'
    try: 
        browser.add_cookie(cookie)
    except Exception as e: 
        print(e)
    

browser.get('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox')

time.sleep(120)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about "don't seem to work"? When the second browser makes requests, does it include the same cookies?

Comment: What happens is that instead of going into Gmail with the account that I had previously logged in with, google asks me for my account again. Yes, when the second request is made, the cookies are the same.